# FAiled to attach Visual Studio 2008 to an application with IronPython on Vista

Tags: visual-studio, ironpython

I'd like to create new command line to attach Visual Studio to an application with IronPython:

My Script:

```
import clr
import System

from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal
DTE = Marshal.GetActiveObject('VisualStudio.DTE')

curLocalProcess = DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses
print curLocalProcess.Count
currentProc = curLocalProcess.Item(1)
currentProc.Attach()
```

While, I encounter a problem on Vista:

```
EnvironmentError: Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. 
To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.
```

I suppose it's not a issue of IronPython but about Vista Security. 
However, I cannot figure out a solution for this even after I run Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and IronPython as Administrator. Except that, I also turned off UAC.

I also notice that "Run this program as an administrator" in Properties - Compatibility tab for Visual Studio is grayed.

Do you have any comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke an elevated VSStudio IDE via script.
Or else run the app & script in Built in Administrator account or in a normal admin account with UAC off.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

         Process p = new Process();

         ProcessStartInfo pp = new ProcessStartInfo();

         pp.Verb = "runas";//Invoke as Admin

         //Do other initialzation.

         p.StartInfo = pp;

         p.Start();
```